# ContractPromise from Polkadot Js do not load contract ABI when intantiating

Tags: polkadot-js, ink

I'm using ReactJs and ContractPromise object can't/don't access contract query and txs object.

```
const contract = new ContractPromise(api,metadata( in json even string format), address);
```

The object instantiated it seems don't actually access the metadata.

```
contract.query // wont access the queries, 
contract.address // will access the address
contract.abi // will access the abi
contract.tx // wont access the transactions
```

Comment: what do you mean won't access the queries and transactions? do you get an error? how did you try to access them? for the flip method on the flipper contract you would do `contract.tx["flip"]` or `contract.tx.flip`

Comment: The issue is the query, txn and other objects are marked as private in the api metadata.

Comment: yes, that is a design decision and very unlikely to change. unless you provide more info on what you are trying to achieve, I am unable to help

Answer (score 1):

Would you please provide more information? For your second argument you can try using an ABI instance. This works for me.

`new Abi(metadata, api.registry.getChainProperties())`

[Here](https://github.com/paritytech/useink/blob/89fc375d309e3cc4e29c75bbca5fcd5c232656ce/core/hooks/contracts/useContract.ts#L24) is a full example from [useink](https://use.ink/frontend/overview), a React hooks library.